# Swift Struct Warning "Initialization of 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer' results in a dangling pointer"

Tags: ios, swift, struct, swift4

I searched many answers for similar questions but can't find the right answer that fixes this. I have a very simple struct

```
  struct MyParameters {
    var position: CGPoint
    var size: Float
  }
```

And then this initialisation

```
 var parameters = MyParameters(position: .zero, size: 0)
 let pointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(&parameters)
```

And I get a warning in the second line

```
 Initialization of 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer' results in a dangling pointer
```

I understand the compiler is complaining as it is not sure whether the memory pointed to by the pointer will continue to exist. But what is the right way to pass pointers in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `withUnsafeMutableBytes`

```
func foo() {
    var parameters = MyParameters(position: .zero, size: 0)
    
    withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &parameters) { pointer in
         // here the lifetime is known
    }
}
```

Comment: But then it gives an error when I use the pointer - Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer'

Comment: You need to access `pointer.baseAddress` to get to the raw pointer